# If $0<p<1$ then $ \sqrt[n] {p} $ converges to 1. Proof

Tags: real-analysis

If $0<p<1$ then  $ \sqrt[n] {p} $ converges to 1.

I understood the proofs for $p \geq 1$. Rudin says that the proof for this case is found by "taking reciprocals". But I'm not sure what he means by this.

Can someone please show me the proof?

Thanks!

Comment: If you have $0\lt p\lt 1$, then you have valid numbers $\tfrac 1p\gt 1$.

Comment: ... as $n \to \infty$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Almost) without words:

$$0<p<1\implies a:=\frac1p>1\implies \frac1{\sqrt[n]p}=\sqrt[n]a\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}1\stackrel{\text{arithmetic of limits}}\implies\sqrt[n]p\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\frac11=1$$

Comment: I think this is what Rudin meant..thanks! all other answers are great too

Answer (score 1):

If $p<1$, then $p^{n+1} < p^n$, and so $p^{1/n} < p^{1/(n+1)}$. Hence the sequence is increasing and bounded above, and so it must converge, to some $a > 0$. Now take logs to see that $\log(a) = 0$ and so $a=1$

Answer (score 1):

$$ \sqrt[n]{p} = \exp(1./n.\log(p)) $$
$$ 1./n.\log(p) \to 0 $$
thus
$$ \sqrt[n]{p} \to \exp(0) = 1$$